# Pressure build up in power steering reservoir

Tags: jeep, power-steering, grand-cherokee

Power steering fluid being forced out of the pump shaft seal -- pressure build up in reservoir. The vehicle is a 93 Jeep Grand Cherokee. I am replacing the pump. Should I expect a pressure build up in the reservoir? Is this a sympton  of pump failure or a problem in the gearbox. Should the gearbox be vented? The pressure build up in the reservoir when removing the cap is likened to opening a bottle of soda.